# Bootstrap Custom Radiobox without Label is dis-aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap4 custom radiobutton and it works fine as long as I use Label text. Sometimes it makes no sense to have text, but then the radiobutton alone is dis-aligend. How can this be fixed?

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1"></label>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Result with and without label]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/51vrL8px/5/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
  <th>Select</th>
  <th>Name</th>
</thead>
<tr>
  <td>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1"></label>
</div>
  </td>
  <td>Sample option 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">with label</label>
</div>
  </td>
  <td>Sample option 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a special character which does not print anything will allow you to get the proper alignment without showing any text next to the radio button.

```
&zwnj;
```

My guess on why it messes up the styling is because of the ::before and ::after code that gets added to the text. If there is no text there is nothing to add the tags to.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">&zwnj;</label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Sample option 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">with label</label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Sample option 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I like this one, cause it's the easiest solution without adding additional classes or even changing the existing ones. Thank you!

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi You are welcome! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `mb-3` class on the empty label

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
  <th>Select</th>
  <th>Name</th>
</thead>
<tr>
  <td>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label mb-3" for="customRadio1"></label>
</div>
  </td>
  <td>Sample option 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">with label</label>
</div>
  </td>
  <td>Sample option 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer shows the same result, are you sure its correct?

Comment: @Granny Can you please check now if its fixed on your device ?

Comment: Its fine now, just wanted to warn you :)

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the heads up :)